# Is there a Node Reference URL Widget module for entity references?

Tags: nodes, entities

I just learned that there is the nice [Node Reference URL Widget](https://drupal.org/project/nodereference_URL) module.  Basically, it allows you to add a *add a A* link in the node view pages of content type B, if there is a node reference A->B.  When you are viewing a B node, clicking on the *add a A* link would lead you to the node creation page of content type A, with the A->B field populated with the B node you were just viewing.  That way the user do not need to figure out "which node B am I adding this node A to?"

Our sites mainly use [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/Entityreference).  Is there a module that provides similar functionality for entity references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.  I see there is [Entityreference prepopulate](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate).

> Allow prepopulating any Entity reference field via URL

Going to try it now.

Comment: Exactly what we are looking for.